# c# is finding a simple math problem wrong?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
Debug.Log(temp3.y + " * " + "(1f - ((" + CurrentSide + " + 1) / (" + Sides + " + 1)))");
Debug.Log( temp3.y * (1f - ((CurrentSide + 1) / (Sides + 1))) );
Debug.Log(((CurrentSide + 1) / (Sides + 1))
```

My outputs are:

> 0.6 * (1f - ((0 + 1) / (1 + 1)))

> 0.6

> 0

why is (0+1) / (1+1) = 0

Comment: (0+1)/(1+1) = 1/2 = 0 R 1. If you want a float number, at least one of the numbers must be float.

Comment: try (0 + 1m) / (1 + 1)

Comment: @semihyılmaz posted this as answer below, please accept it as the answer it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs atleast one of the operand to be a floating point type (decimal, double or float).

Below is an example with an int and floating point types:

```
var intValue =  (0 + 1) / (1 + 1) // 1/2 = 0 (datatype is int)
var decimalValue = (0 + 1m) / (1 + 1)// 1/2 = 0.5 (datatype is decimal)
var floatValue = (0 + 1f) / (1 + 1)// 1/2 = 0.5 (datatype is float)
var doubleValue = (0 + 1d) / (1 + 1)// 1/2 = 0.5 (datatype is double)
```

in this case the numerator is a decimal, so the result of the operation is a decimal as well.

Look into integer and floating point divisions in C#.

Comment: _"It needs atleast one of the operand to be a decimal."_ - no, it does not need specifically `decimal`, `float` or `double` will do just fine too.

Answer (score 1):

You have found an example of integer division.

(0+1)/(1+1) = 1/2 = 0 R 1. The `/` operator gives you the 0 part of the result, the `%` operator gives you the 1 of the result.

If you want a floating point number, at least one of the numbers must be a floating point number. Try

```cs
Debug.Log(((CurrentSide + 1.0) / (Sides + 1.0)
```